# Check if a character typed in a PasswordBox is numeric or not

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have researched a little and it seems that there is not `InputScope` for passwordboxes in xaml. I'm setting up a pin field and only want numbers. if figure i will need to check the if the key pressed is numeric in C# before it writes it to the box. how would i go about doing this? it will also be checking if the length is 4 so it can automatically login which i already know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe for `KeyDown` event on the `PasswordBox`.  Maxmum Length can be restricted by setting `MaxLength` property.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9))          
    return;

    e.Handled = true;            
}
```

Comment: This worked great! I appeared i already did this once with a phone number Textbox and didnt even remember. I also added the tab and shift+tab to it for when creating the pin and confirming it so the users can tab and shift tab still.

Answer (score 0):

```
@edited

Xaml:
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" MaxLength="4" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"/>

private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string password = "pass";
    int result;
    bool isPasswordNumeric = int.TryParse(password , out result);

    if (!isPasswordNumeric)
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every change of the password, that is on every keystroke, you could just discard all non-numeric characters. The user's experience would be that the control responds only to numeric characters.

```
private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
    string inputString = passwordBox.Password;
    string cleanString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[^0-9]", "");
    passwordBox.Password = cleanString;
    return;
}
```

Please notice that the caret character (`^`) in the regular expresion negates the search field, i.e. it replaces all characters other than 0-9 with an empty string.

Use the XAML from Pawel Maga's post.